# Notification for voting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, election

I just voted in [the SO Moderator elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) today (awesome!).  However, I wasn't sure if my vote was registered, because there wasn't any alert.  (I did receive a badge, but that was 10-15 minutes later.)

I think we should change the message from "0 votes remaining" to "**You've used all your votes.  Thanks for voting!** Remember, you can come back and change your votes before the election ends"

Comment: There is clear feedback on the right-hand side, where your 3 choices are shown as you make them. Sorry, no screenshot as the vote is private until the end of the election.

Comment: There's "You are in the voting process" feedback and "Thanks for voting" feedback.  Your example is the former to me.  I'd prefer feedback that eliminates the guesswork.

Comment: I've changed your question to the format how feature requests are usually done on meta (you shouldn't take the "must be a question" thing too seriously here; the implied question is always "Do you agree with this feature request? Do you see alternatives, shortcomings, etc.?")

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the time to explain that to me.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MartijnPieters actually the vote is still anonymous after that.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Right, vote tallies vs. individual votes. The tallies will be opened after the election.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good idea, and will be the case after the next build. Maybe a bit late for this particular election, but at least there for those to come.