# Introduce a clear visual indicator that confirms that one's vote counts in the election

Tags: feature-request, election

During our current election on rpg.se multiple times, we have encountered uncertainty about whether dragging and dropping our candidates inside the voting box is sufficient for voting or if one has to confirm their action.

Users are uncertain about whether they voted correctly despite the visual indicators - receiving a badge and the timer that counts down pending save in 5 to 1.

Could we get a feature in the "Your ballot" box that indicates that one's vote counts? E. g. a bold coloured text that says: You voted! You still have time to change your ballot until the election ends.

Comment: [similar FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136530/1017231) before the [major election overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361979/moderator-elections-functionality-voting-ui-commenting-and-flagging)

Comment: Thanks for asking this, the previous elections had such a confirmation.

Comment: See also a similar support question on [ELU meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15256/191178).

Comment: there is still some glitch in Ballot saving: the auto-save message says "Selections saved" but when I refresh the page, the vote is not saved. I let my selection 1 day but today I refresh and all candidate went out of the box.

Answer (score 18):

This does not only confuse rpg.se users, this also frequently comes up in the tex.se election chat. A couple of examples after two days of voting:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59453605#59453605
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59453631#59453631
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59445957#59445957
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59448011#59448011

---

I propose an explicit save button. The automatic saving seems to work fine, but from a psychological point of view, I would prefer to hit some button, so I feel certain that the votes are really submitted.

Mock-up:

[image]

Comment: The save button doesn't even need to do anything other than make a <div> visible.

Comment: Well, if there is a save button, it should do something: If I rearrange my vote and then don't press save, I would expect my previous vote to still be in effect.